# Boot From EFI File Option Not Listed!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, windows-10

I am a windows User But Currently, I am Trying To Install Ubuntu On a Single boot. I Just Downloaded Ubuntu ISO File. I didn't have a USB flash drive so I downloaded Ubuntu on a hard drive with a tool called Universal USB Installer 2.0.0.1 when I restarted my PC (my pc is a dell vostro win 10 PC) I didn't get the option to boot Ubuntu. I have legacy support enabled, my partition style is **GPT**. Can anyone help me to get rid of this problem?

Comment: If Windows 10 and drive is gpt, then it is UEFI. Some older Dell systems needed legacy on but still boot in UEFI mode. What version of Ubuntu? Should use latest LTS or 22.04. Newer systems need UEFI on and legacy, BIOS, CSM mode off. Most tools to install ISO, totally erase that drive as it overwrites partition table at beginning of drive. Is Windows fast start up on, that sets hibernation flag & Linux NTFS driver cannot fully see the NTFS partitions, even if you want to erase them. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2465052